# UITableView remove disclosure indicator and selection on rows that are not editable in canEditRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with multiple sections. Only the first section is editable/selectable via canEditRowAt.

For the other sections that are not editable/selectable, their disclosure indicator remains. I can disable selection BUT I want the disclosure indicators to go away so the user knows that these rows can't be tapped when in edit mode. Any ideas?

I could reload the table and toggle the .accessoryType but reloading the table kills the system animation in setEditing(true, animated: true).

Comment: [Edit] your question with relevant code (as text, not a picture).

Answer (score 2):

To remove all disclosure indicators visible, try this snippet:

```
self.tableView.visibleCells.forEach {
    $0.accessoryType = .none
}
```

This will not kill any system animation, or other things. You can of course add a test inside the loop to choose the cells you want to remove or not the accessory!

Comment: Would you recommend that I call run this after calling self.tableView.setEditing()? I assume I'll need to refresh the cells to get it to display correct? Or is there a delegate I should run this in?